# Expecting a variable list of arguments in PHPUnit

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I have an adapter that has a method taking a variable list of arguments and forwards it to a method that takes those same arguments in a framework I am using. I want to test that my adapter correctly forwards the arguments. I however do not want my test to know about which kind of arguments the framework supports.

I have a working expects as follows:

```
$context->expects( $this->once() )
    ->method( 'msg' )
    ->with(
        $this->equalTo( $someMessageArguments[0] ),
        $this->equalTo( $someMessageArguments[1] ),
        $this->equalTo( $someMessageArguments[2] )
    );
```

This is clearly not good as it assumes the length of the variable list is 3. I want to use a data provider and test with different lengths as well, in which case this code won't cut it.

Is there a sane way to do this via the PHPUnit API? I hacked this up, which also works, though seems quite evil as well:

```
$invocationMocker = $context->expects( $this->once() )
    ->method( 'msg' );

$invocationMocker->getMatcher()->parametersMatcher
    = new PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Matcher_Parameters( $someMessageArguments );
```

In case there is no way to do this nicely via the PHPUnit API, is there an approach that is better then the two listed here?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found the way to do it with PHPUnit mocks.

Using Mockery, you can archieve that:

```
$mock->shouldReceive('msg')
     ->once()
     ->withArgs($someMessageArguments);
```

Personally I normally prefer Mockery over PHPUnit mocks.

https://github.com/padraic/mockery

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do something similar with `withConsecutive`.

After building an array of my arguments for consecutive calls, the following was used.

```
$invocationMocker->getMatcher()->setParametersMatcher(new Matcher\ConsecutiveParameters($arguments));
```

The PHPUnit interface and namespace has changed a little since the original post.